# Compare current and given times with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Before you flag this post down, you should know that I have searched extensively...

I have a time for an event and need to compare to current time to determine if it has passed or not.

```
<div class="myEvent" data-time="17:00">5:00 PM</div>
```

I think the best will be to convert both to milliseconds and compare.

```
var today   = new Date();
var current = today.getTime();  
var given   = $('.myEvent').attr('data-time');
```

But here's where I get stuck... How do I convert given time to milliseconds?

Comment: `(new Date()).getTime()` will return number of milliseconds since 1 January of 1970. And `data-time` has only information about time; no year, month, day. You want to compare only time?

Comment: Yes, the times are all on the same date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)**;

```js
var today = Date.now(),
    given = $('.myEvent').attr('data-time'),
    givenMs = Date.parse(new Date().toDateString() + ' ' + given);

console.log(givenMs);
```

Answer (score 1):

Date.parse('01/01/2015 10:10:10') is the function you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) a simple library to construct and [compare](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#compare) dates in javascript.

```
var hour = parseInt($(".myEvent").attr("data-time"))
var givenHour = Date.today().set({ hour : hour  });
Date.compare(Date.today().setTimeToNow(), givenHour) === 1
```